# Gson error whenever the returned object is empty

Tags: java, android

am using gson

So my request is

```
@Override
public void onApiResonse(JSONObject response) {
   ReportsOverviewDto dto = gjson.fromJson(response.toString(), ReportsOverviewDto.class);
   ArrayList<ReportsOverviewDto.DataOverviewDto> data = dto.getData();

 }
```

So in my class `ReportsOverviewDto`

I have

```
public class ReportsOverviewDto {
  private ArrayList<DataOverviewDto> data;
  private String date_from, date_to;
    ...getters and setters and other classes

}
```

Now when the data is returned as

```
{"data":[{"total":588,"truck_category":26},
         {"total":1646,"truck_category":27,},
         {"total":1523,"truck_category":28}
       ],"date_to":"29\/03\/2018 03:03",
        "date_from":"29\/03\/2017 03:03"}
```

Whenever server finds no records it returns the data in form of
    "data":{},"date_to":"29/03/2018 03:03","date_from":"29/03/2018 03:03"}
Now with the second response where the data is `{}` am getting an error of

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 10 path $.data
```

I fully understand this is because when its empty the data type is no longer an arraylist but just an object.

How do i ensure that even when its empty the app doesnt simply crash

Comment: is it possible to get the api to return `"data":[],` rather than `"data":{},` when there are no results. Not cool that the object type changes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the server side as it returns an `empty Object {}` instead of an `empty Array []`. However, if want to make changes on the client side only, these would help:

1. Convert the JSON response into `Map<String,Object>` using `fromJson()`.
2. Loop through the map and correct the invalid entries in the map. In this case, if a entry has `key=="data"` and value is NOT an `ArrayList`, then convert that entry value to an empty `ArrayList`.
3. Form back the JSON String from the filtered map (from step #2) using `toJson()`.
4. Convert the well-formatted JSON String (from step #3) to your `ReportsOverviewDto dto` using `fromJson()`.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

look the picture ,check on Json formmat  Entity class  is right

```
enter code here
```

public class ReportsOverviewDto {

```
/**
 * data : [{"total":588,"truck_category":26},{"total":1646,"truck_category":27},{"total":1523,"truck_category":28}]
 * date_to : 29/03/2018 03:03
 * date_from : 29/03/2017 03:03
 */

private String date_to;
private String date_from;
private List<DataBean> data;
public static List<ReportsOverviewDto> arrayReportsOverviewDtoFromData(String str) {

    Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<ReportsOverviewDto>>() {
    }.getType();

    return new Gson().fromJson(str, listType);
}
public String getDate_to() {
    return date_to;
}
public void setDate_to(String date_to) {
    this.date_to = date_to;
}
public String getDate_from() {
    return date_from;
}
public void setDate_from(String date_from) {
    this.date_from = date_from;
}
public List<DataBean> getData() {
    return data;
}
public void setData(List<DataBean> data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public static class DataBean {
    /**
     * total : 588
     * truck_category : 26
     */

    private int total;
    private int truck_category;

    public static List<DataBean> arrayDataBeanFromData(String str) {

        Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<DataBean>>() {
        }.getType();

        return new Gson().fromJson(str, listType);
    }

    public int getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public void setTotal(int total) {
        this.total = total;
    }

    public int getTruck_category() {
        return truck_category;
    }

    public void setTruck_category(int truck_category) {
        this.truck_category = truck_category;
    }
}
```

}